# Install Shiny Server and Rstudio Server on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: r, raspberry-pi, rstudio

I'm trying to install Rstudio server and shiny server in Raspberry Pi 3. It has a ARM architecture which is same as many chromebooks. There are serveral sources I've found 
but non of them seems to work. Here I'm listing the sources related to this topics, any help in this direction will be helpful. I have been able to install the latest version of
R in Raspberry Pi in Debian Jessie.

1. https://github.com/jrowen/ARM-rstudio-server/blob/master/build_rstudio.sh (install rstudio server on chromebook)
2. https://github.com/trestletech/RpiR (ubuntu image including shiny server)
3. blog on install shiny server on raspberry pi is available in  withr.me.

Any help in this direction will be helpful.

Comment: I've been trying to get Shiny server running on a Pi2 for a while with no success as yet. I get to a trace-point error when trying to run `sudo shiny-server start`, which seems to be where a lot of people are getting. I'd love to get a method together for doing it that works. What issue are you coming up against specifically?

Comment: Also, here's another source, but I (and others) can't seem to get it working http://withr.me/install-shiny-server-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: For future viewers: you might want to check out this post: https://community.rstudio.com/t/setting-up-your-own-shiny-server-rstudio-server-on-a-raspberry-pi-3b/18982 from this forum: https://community.rstudio.com/t/raspberry-pi-as-a-viable-shiny-server/18672